# Fast query to do normalization on SQL data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some data that I want to normalize. Specifically I'm normalizing it so I can process the portions getting normalized without having to worry about duplicates. What I'm doing is:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (a, b, c)
    SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c
    FROM old_table;

UPDATE old_table
SET abc_id = new_table.id
FROM new_table
WHERE new_table.a = old_table.a 
  AND new_table.b = old_table.b  
  AND new_table.c = old_table.c;
```

First off, it seems as if there should be a better way of doing this. It seems that the inherent process of finding the distinct data could produce a list of the members that belong to it. Second, and more important, the INSERT takes a couple and the UPDATE takes **FOREVER** (I don't actually have a value for how long it takes yet because it's still running). I'm using postgresql. Is there a better way of doing this (perhaps all in one query).

Comment: If the UPDATE takes _FOREVER_, then could it be that you're missing a `unique index on new_table (a, b, c)` ?

Comment: Did you `analyze old_table; analyze new_table;` first of all?

Comment: @EgorRogov I did not, but now doing that it just says "ANALYZE". I then read the documentation which says that it "collects statics", but I'm not sure I exactly understand what it's supposed to be doing. Am I supposed to glean some information from that or is it just a magical way of making queries go faster?

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister I didn't have an index those columns, because I didn't think I'd use it in the future. I have added one, and it's still extremely slow.

Comment: @CrazyCasta Kind of magical way, yeah. You're giving the planner a chance to do its work better. If this didn't help, can you show the execution plan (`explain update old_table ...`) and also how many rows do you have in both tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my other answer, extended to three columns:

```
        -- Some test data
CREATE TABLE the_table
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , name varchar
        , a INTEGER
        , b varchar
        , c varchar
        );
INSERT INTO the_table(name, a,b,c) VALUES
 ( 'Chimpanzee' , 1, 'mammals', 'apes' )
,( 'Urang Utang' , 1, 'mammals', 'apes' )
,( 'Homo Sapiens' , 1, 'mammals', 'apes' )
,( 'Mouse' , 2, 'mammals', 'rodents' )
,( 'Rat' , 2, 'mammals', 'rodents' )
,( 'Cat' , 3, 'mammals', 'felix' )
,( 'Dog' , 3, 'mammals', 'canae' )
        ;

        -- [empty] table to contain the "squeezed out" domain {a,b,c}
CREATE TABLE abc_table
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , a INTEGER
        , b varchar
        , c varchar
        , UNIQUE (a,b,c)
        );

        -- The original table needs a "link" to the new table
ALTER TABLE the_table
        ADD column abc_id INTEGER -- NOT NULL
        REFERENCES abc_table(id)
        ;
        -- FK constraints are helped a lot by a supportive index.
CREATE INDEX abc_table_fk ON the_table (abc_id);

        -- Chained query to:
        -- * populate the domain table
        -- * initialize the FK column in the original table
WITH ins AS (
        INSERT INTO abc_table(a,b,c)
        SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c
        FROM the_table a
        RETURNING *
        )
UPDATE the_table ani
SET abc_id = ins.id
FROM ins
WHERE ins.a = ani.a
AND ins.b = ani.b
AND ins.c = ani.c
        ;

        -- Now that we have the FK pointing to the new table,
        -- we can drop the redundant columns.
ALTER TABLE the_table DROP COLUMN a, DROP COLUMN b, DROP COLUMN c;

SELECT * FROM the_table;
SELECT * FROM abc_table;

        -- show it to the world
SELECT a.*
        , c.a, c.b, c.c
FROM the_table a
JOIN abc_table c ON c.id = a.abc_id
        ;
```

---

Results:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 7
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE INDEX
UPDATE 7
ALTER TABLE
 id |     name     | abc_id 
----+--------------+--------
  1 | Chimpanzee   |      4
  2 | Urang Utang  |      4
  3 | Homo Sapiens |      4
  4 | Mouse        |      3
  5 | Rat          |      3
  6 | Cat          |      1
  7 | Dog          |      2
(7 rows)

 id | a |    b    |    c    
----+---+---------+---------
  1 | 3 | mammals | felix
  2 | 3 | mammals | canae
  3 | 2 | mammals | rodents
  4 | 1 | mammals | apes
(4 rows)

 id |     name     | abc_id | a |    b    |    c    
----+--------------+--------+---+---------+---------
  1 | Chimpanzee   |      4 | 1 | mammals | apes
  2 | Urang Utang  |      4 | 1 | mammals | apes
  3 | Homo Sapiens |      4 | 1 | mammals | apes
  4 | Mouse        |      3 | 2 | mammals | rodents
  5 | Rat          |      3 | 2 | mammals | rodents
  6 | Cat          |      1 | 3 | mammals | felix
  7 | Dog          |      2 | 3 | mammals | canae
(7 rows)
```

Comment: As per my comment above: http://pastebin.com/P7wtCxYx . This doesn't seem to be any better then my original queries with a unique constraint on the new table.

Comment: With primary keys, a foreign key and a supporting index, it is different. And probably better.

Comment: Ok, after a ton of looking at it yours does perform a hash join IF you do the insert before you add the new column. I'm not exactly sure why, but it seems to be VERY VERY picky about the order things are done in, even if the result is the same (i.e. I can't just create the table with the foreign key already in it) This is probably a problem for my case, but it does look like it might work in certain cases. Sadly SO won't let me un-downvote it :(

Comment: Normally you would do a `vacuum analyze` between the filling of the domain table and the update (and maybe move the index creation there, too). In this example, I used a chained insert+update, which needs the supporting index on the base table. And ,as I said, the hash join is temporarily. Once the tables have non-trivial sizes (and statistics are available) some index join will be preferred.

Comment: Well, that took about 4 hours for 4.5 million rows. I'm pretty sure at this point though that the issue is my gcloud IOPS suck because I have too small of a drive :(

Comment: P.S. A bit off topic, but do you know if the OS buffers in RAM will help for writes or does postgresql demand that the filesystem write it back to disk before it moves on (by opening O_SYNC or calling fsync)?

Comment: Normally, postgres issues fsync()s at strategic points ( ~:= at the end of transactions). Also make sure that you hardware honours these requests; some NAS or RAID devices ignore them by default. Correct fsync() behaviour is absolutely necessary for  crash recovery. See the docs for details.

Comment: Yeah, I was more thinking that if I upgrade the machine type to have larger RAM that the update might run faster.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a way to do this on my own:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_table_temp (
    LIKE new_table,
    old_ids integer[]
)
ON COMMIT DROP;

INSERT INTO new_table_temp (a, b, c, old_ids)
    SELECT a, b, c, array_ag(id) AS old_ids
    FROM old_table
    GROUP BY a, b, c;

INSERT INTO new_table (id, a, b, c)
    SELECT id, a, b, c
    FROM new_table_temp;

UPDATE old_table
SET abc_id = new_table_temp.id
FROM new_table_temp
WHERE old_table.id = ANY(new_table_temp.old_ids);

COMMIT;
```

This at least is what I was looking for. I'll update this as to whether it worked quickly. The `EXPLAIN` seems to form a sensible plan, so I'm hopeful.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29879536/905902 (replace {category, subcategory} by your {a,b,c} columns. Don't forget the unique on {a,b,c} and the FK/PK constraints! )

Comment: Ok, I just took a look at that, uness I put a unique index on the first table it's going to do an awful lot of work. http://pastebin.com/P7wtCxYx According to that explain it has to pull up the table, do a sequential scan and sort the keys. Mine results in a hash lookup for the id.

Comment: The hash -->> index switch is dictated by (the absense of) statistics and indexes. Without additional information, the planner often chooses the hash solution, unless the hashtable is expected to not fit into memory. BTW: with the small test data my solution yields a hashtable, too.