# Refactoring one Postgres table into several tables

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, refactoring-databases

Let's say I have a table with the following columns:

`id | address | city | state`

Now let's say I want to take the data from that table and move it into 3 new tables:

Table 1 ("addresses"):

`id | address | city_id`

Table 2 ("cities"):

`id | city | state_id`

Table 3 ("states"):

`id | state`

I've seen a few answers involving data-modifying CTEs, but they're not very clear and I'm having trouble understanding how I would do something like what I described above.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? This should be solvable through some INSERT and SELECT queries in your application

Comment: Maybe. I'm not clear at all on how to do that. After Googling around some more it looks like what I'm trying to do is normalize the data. At this point I'm trying to find a comprehensible explanation of how to actually do it. Most of what I'm finding is explanations of the concept itself.

Comment: 1) create the new tables 2) populate them 3) drop the old table 4) profit!

Comment: There is no generic approach to refactor, but writing some code for your specific problem should not be that hard for you :)

Comment: @wildplasser, it doesn't seem to be as simple as that. How do I go about populating the third column of table 2 with the ids from table 3 when those ids won't exist until later (when I populate table 3)?

Comment: It is simple.Both`id` columns should be serials, and the other column(s) are  are the natural key for them.The only complication is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_(disambiguation) , which implies a composite key for your `table2`

Comment: Honestly, I'm not trying to be a jerk at all, but while that may seem simple to you, it's not simple to me. There was probably a time in your journey when it wouldn't have been simple to you, either. Do you happen to know of anywhere I can see an example of the queries that would produce the result I'm looking for?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37734162/905902 , for example.